# how to create a scope of elements not yet in many to many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, arel

I have created a "many to many" relationship using a has_many :through join table.

```
class ProductType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assemblies
  has_many :components, through: :assemblies
end

class Assembly < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product_type
  belongs_to :component
end

class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assemblies
  has_many :product_types, through: :assemblies
end
```

From the complete list of components, I can select a few and add them to the product_type
but I should only be allowed to add them once, so the list of components to add from, should only show the components that have NOT yet been added.

I currently have it working with 
1) the list of already added components

```
@product_type.components
```

2) the list of not yet added ones

```
Component.all - @product_type.components
```

This works, but, I would like to create a scope on the components model so that something like

```
@product_type.components.addable
```

would generate that second list of not yet added components.

Is this possible? If yes, what would the code be on the components model? or would it go in ProductType? (I havent found anything that works)
Also, is there a name for this list of not yet added components? Would it be a "right outer join"? if not, what?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely possible.  Below is a snippet that shows a scope which should be added to the component model

```
scope :addable_to_product_type, -> (product_type) { joins("LEFT JOIN assemblies ON assemblies.component_id = components.id AND assemblies.product_type_id = #{product_type.id}").where("assemblies.component_id IS NULL") }
```

Usage would be something like this:

```
Component.addable_to_product_type(@product_type)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried it, but I get this error SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: assemblies.product_type_id:

Comment: I suspect you're still using the components relation on the product type object.  Since you're looking for components which do not have assemblies,
    Component.addable
would be preferable to
    @product_type.components.addable

Comment: Thats correct, but the addable components are per product_type. Not generic. Each product_type has a list of already added components and its own personal list of addable components. If I do a Component.addable, that would give me a list of components not yet on any product_type.

Comment: Yup, that seems to have worked! Thanks. If you dont mind me asking a few things. 1) is it not possible to do it as I wanted (@product_type.components.addable)  ?   2)  is this Arel? 3) I assume this is a common operation, does it have a name? I wasnt able to find a solution searching with any of the descriptions I gave it. thanks!

Comment: 1. Unfortunately, using the components association on a given product_type wouldn't work, as rails uses INNER JOINs for these and would return components that are associated with the product type.  Because of this, even using a table alias in the scope query would result in undesired (and unexpected) results.
2. If you're referring to the arel gem, then no.  These are just vanilla rails syntax and methods.
3. I'm unsure if there is a more specific name for this, other than maybe exclusive left join.